# ASP.NET 4.6 and ASP.NET Core 1.0 sharing authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, asp.net-core, iis-express

I have an old ASP.NET 4.6 with a mix of WebForms and MVC.

I'm starting a new project with React/Redux and I would like to host it on the new ASP.NET Core 1.0 (running on .NET 4.6).

On the long run (think years) the new project is expected to replace the old one, but in the interval, I would like to have back and forth navigation between the old pages and the new single page application. The idea is that customers can use the old version of the features until we ship the new version. I'm also thinking about using iframes, depending on the needs.

Question is : can we host both on the same domain, with one being in a virtual directory, like:

- Old webapp: http://www.mycompany.com/
- New webapp: http://www.mycompany.com/SPA/

And also, can they share authentication, with a domain cookie, with login pages being on the old app?

I've been trying to start both web projects in IIS Express, but they don't seem to want to work together.

If you have examples of applications doing this, I'd love to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing.html#sharing-authentication-cookies-between-asp-net-4-x-and-asp-net-5-applications

But migrating the old ASP.NET 4.6 app to Katana is out of question.